# Extracting images with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my first post on this forum, so apologies if I'm missing anything!

Basically, I have had some success with the script(seen below), however, it is only returning one image(being the last image on the page).

Any help is appreciated!

```
import scrapy

class KwikEKartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kek"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/fresh-food/all"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/fresh-food/all',
    )

def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath("//img/@src")
    html = ""
    
    for link in links:
        url = link.get()
    
    if any(extension in url for extension in
    [".jpg", ".png"]):
        html += """<a href="{url}"
        target="_blank">
        <img src="{url}" height="33%"
        width="33%"/>
        <a/>""".format(url=url)

    with open("frontpage.html", "a") as page:
        page.write(html)
        page.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an indentation problem.

The only line inside your for loop is:

```
url = link.get()
```

You probably want to indent the rest of the code as well.